# XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://..... Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) for $http post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cors, lumen

Here is my angularjs $http post request

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://...',
        data: {matric:u.matric, faculty:u.faculty, department:u.department, level:u.level, password:u.password},


      }).success(function(){
      $scope.passwor = '';
       $scope.erro = '';
        $scope.matri = '';
    $state.go('login');
  }).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
      $scope.erro = 'Please Try Again. Check Your Connection ';
           $scope.matri =error.matric[0];
     $scope.passwor =error.password[0];


  }).finally(function() { 
    loader.hide();
    });
```

my api is written in lumen and i have added palanik/lumencors already to all the routes.
I have also search for solution online but nothing seems to work for me. please help !!!.ihave this in my controller

```
public function option()
    {
      return true;
    }
```

and this in my route.php

```
 $app->options('/', 'matricController@option');
    $app->post('/','matricController@store');
```

also this code that return okay(200) for OPTIONS

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }
        $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: The error response seems clear: The server responded with a redirect during the CORS preflight request. It should not do that.

Comment: i know, but i do not  know how to stop that. it runs well on postman but not on mobile devices and my web browser. please how can i solve the redirect issue. Thanks

Comment: A trailing slash on the URL can cause this. Fiddler shows the permanent redirect to the same URL without slash.

Comment: having a trailing slash on urls always messes me up with requests.

Answer (score 2):

When not doing a "simple" request, the browser send a so called pre-flight OPTIONS request to the server, which you have to respond with a status 200. So simply setting the CORS-headers isn't enough.

I'm guessing your server is lacking a route for an OPTIONS request and responds with a redirect to some placeholder or an errorpage perhaps?

You can read more about the pre-flight request on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: $app->options('/', 'matricController@option');
    $app->post('/','matricController@store');

Comment: `public function option()
    {
      return true;
    }`

Comment: i have the option route set up already, but still having that error. Also having a middleware(palanik/lumencors) that return ok(200) for OPTIONS

Comment: is this issue occur for wrong route or wrong request  method ?